# mysql decimal round

Tags: mysql, decimal, truncate, rounding

I'm new to mysql and need some basic things.

I need to round the decimals like :

21,4758 should be 21,48

0,2250 should be  0,22

23,0850 should be  23,08

22,9950 should be  22,99

I tried lots of thing but couldn't make it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DECLARE @old decimal(38, 10)
DECLARE @p decimal(38, 10)
SET @p = 21.4758

SET @p = @p * 100
SET @p = @p - 0.01
SET @p = ROUND(@p, 0)
SET @p = @p / 100.0
SELECT @p
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
// round the value to two decimal places 
SELECT ROUND(<YOUR_FIELD>, 2) field FROM <YOUR_TABLE>
// use truncate if you don't wan't to round the actual value
SELECT TRUNCATE(<YOUR_FIELD>, 2) field FROM <YOUR_TABLE>
// you can also use round or truncate depending whether the third decimal is > 5
SELECT IF(SUBSTR(<YOUR_FIELD>, 5, 1) > 5, 
   ROUND(<YOUR_FIELD>, 2), 
   TRUNCATE(<YOUR_FIELD>, 2)) field 
FROM <YOUR_TABLE>;
```

The above isn't a complete solution, but perhaps it will point you in the right direction.

Read the documentation for [`mysql round()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) and [`mysql truncate()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate)

Comment: it makes 0,2250 to 0,23. doesn't work. 0,2250 should be 0,22.

Comment: @Can - I updated my answer, you should use `truncate` over `round`, though you wanted to round the value as well.

Comment: yes thanks Krister, it worked the first three. but this time, 22,9950 returns 23..

Comment: @Can - I don't understand why not just round the numbers in an ordinary fashion?