# Get to 2 decimal places

Tags: mysql, decimal, truncate

I have this line of query here

```
if (type = 1,

(IF(ISNULL(users), 
'', 
((SUM(actual) / 1) * 0.04/12) * if(users = "user", booked/(36/12),'')
))

,
'false')
```

the example output is `123.3333333`

I want it to output just 2 decimals so it'll be like `123.33` where should I place the Truncate or Round command?

Thank You!

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541650/mysql-decimal-round?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190668/format-number-to-2-decimal-places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [truncate()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function%5ftruncate)

```
TRUNCATE(123.3333333, 2) = 123.33


if (type = 1,
(
  IF(ISNULL(users), '', 
  TRUNCATE(
  (
    (SUM(actual) / 1) * 0.04/12) * if(users_0.user_name = "user", booked/(36/12),'')
  ),2)

)

,
'false')
```

Comment: @hearmeroar what syntax error? Did you try fixing it yourself? You should be more helpful to the person who is helping you.

Comment: sorry about that I added the truncate function in a wrong place.. to many parentheses confused me. Just corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
if (type = 1,
(IF(ISNULL(users), '', ROUND(((SUM(actual) / 1) * 0.04/12) * if(users_0.user_name = "user", booked/(36/12),''),2)))
, 'false')
```

Comment: I edited my line of query in the description box. Tried it like this but I got a syntax error

Comment: Updated to your new query.